# Keep div opened on hover while moving between divs (using jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouseover

thanks for reading.

Currently, the following is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.withdraw_money').hover(function(){
        if ($("#withdraw_money_div").is(":hidden")){
            $("#withdraw_money_div").slideDown("slow")
        }else{
            $("#withdraw_money_div").hide()
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Okay. So, I'm able to get the div(#withdraw_money_div) to slide down when the other div(.withdraw_money) is on hover . But my problem now is how can i make the div continue to stay on hover when i shift my mouse over to #withdraw_money_div?

I just can't seem to find a way to do it. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

in your HTML put `#withdraw_money_div` into `'.withdraw_money'` , making a child and therefore you will still be on `.withdraw_money` hover event

ALSO..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.withdraw_money').hover(function(){
    if ($("#withdraw_money_div").is(":hidden")){
        $("#withdraw_money_div").slideDown("slow")
    }else{                            // why is this here?
     $("#withdraw_money_div").hide() //if div isn't hidden(shown) you're hiding it!!
    }
  });
});
```

I would suggest `.mouseOver` or `.hover`with 2 functions , it will cover mouse over and a function for when you hover out of div - I think that is what you ment by else statement

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo** try this http://jsfiddle.net/YuBNT/

Hope it fits the cause `:)`

**Code**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#withdraw_money_div").hide();
        $('.withdraw_money').hover(function() {
            $("#withdraw_money_div").slideDown("slow")


        }, function() {
            $("#withdraw_money_div").slideUp("slow")

        });
    });​
```

Comment: i'm assuming his html was't written with "#withdraw_money_div" as a child of '.withdraw_money' like it is in your fiddle - otherwise his code would already work

Comment: @ScottSelby thanks for comment - Well, hope Html will be given by OP soon, but the dmoe will give him/her better idea, `:)`